# python re replace all between tags

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am looking for a python regular expression that will replace all occurrence of `pattern` with `replace_pattern` between `start` and `end`.

Example:

```
start fkdsjflsd pattern jdflsdjf pattern end
```

will yeild

```
start fkdsjflsd replace_pattern jdflsdjf replace_pattern end
```

I have managed to do it in a `for` loop:

```
pattern = 'start(?P<before1>.*)' + pattern
while re.findall(pattern, content, flags=re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE):

    repl = 'start\g<before1>' + replace_pattern
    content = re.sub(pattern, repl, content, flags=re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: is that the  `start` and `end` strings are properly closed?

Comment: I did it in a loop while re.find(pattern). which was very slow... should I add it to the question?

Comment: @yonatan Yes always add your attempted solution to the question.

Comment: did you have any problem in importing regex module?

Comment: You don't need regex to do this, a simple .replace('pattern','replace_pattern') will work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, `start` and `end` are properly closed

Comment: @yonatan did you want to match the string pattern in `foopatternbar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the start and end strings or properly enclosed then you could use the below regex to match the string `pattern` . Then replace the matched string `pattern` with `replace_pattern` through `re.sub` function.

```
(?<!\S)pattern(?!\S)(?=(?:(?!(?<!\S)(?:start|end)(?!\S)).)*?(?<!\S)end(?!\S))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM6bF5/2)

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: s = "pattern foo start fkdsjflsd pattern jdflsdjf pattern end pattern"

In [8]: re.sub(r'(?<!\S)pattern(?!\S)(?=(?:(?!(?<!\S)(?:start|end)(?!\S)).)*?(?<!\S)end(?!\S))', r'replace_pattern', s)
Out[8]: 'pattern foo start fkdsjflsd replace_pattern jdflsdjf replace_pattern end pattern'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\bpattern\b(?=(?:(?!\bend\b|\bstart\b).)*\bend\b(?:(?:(?!\bstart\b|\bend\b).)*\bstart\b(?:(?!\bend\b|\bstart\b).)*\bend\b)*(?:(?!\bstart\b|\bend\b).)*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/30

```
    import re
p = re.compile(ur'pattern(?=(?:(?!\bend\b|\bstart\b).)*\bend\b(?:(?:(?!\bstart\b|\bend\b).)*\bstart\b(?:(?!\bend\b|\bstart\b).)*\bend\b)*(?:(?!\bstart\b|\bend\b).)*$)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"pattern start fkdsjflsd pattern jdflsdjf pattern end pattern"
subst = u"replace_pattern"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: this replaces the string pattern present in this `foopatternbar` also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj doesnt now

Comment: @yonatan did this fail in any case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
>>> import re
>>> a='start fkdsjflsd pattern jdflsdjf pattern end'
>>> re.sub(r'(start\s+.*?)pattern\s+(.*?end)',r'\1 replace_pattern \2',a)
'start fkdsjflsd  replace_pattern jdflsdjf pattern end'
```